# Loop is faster with fixed limit

Tags: c++, linux, performance, for-loop, g++

This loop:

```
long n = 0;
unsigned int i, j, innerLoopLength = 4;
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < innerLoopLength; j++) {
        n += v[j];
    }
}
```

finishes in 0 ms, while this one:

```
long n = 0;
unsigned int i, j, innerLoopLength = argc;
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < innerLoopLength; j++) {
        n += v[j];
    }
}
```

takes 35 ms.
No matter what the innerLoopLength is, the first method is always pretty fast while the second getting slower and slower.

Does anybody know why and is there a way to speed up the seconds version? I'm grateful for every ms.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<long> v;
    cout << "argc: " << argc << endl;
    for (long l = 1; l <= argc; l++) {
        v.push_back(l);
    }

    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    long n = 0;
    unsigned int i, j, innerLoopLength = 4;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < innerLoopLength; j++) {
            n += v[j];
        }
    }

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "duration: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count() / 1000.0 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "n: " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with -std=c++1z and -O3.

Comment: Check the compiled machine code to be sure, but the compiler likely optimized the first version and unrolled the inner loop, whereas the second version could not be optimized the same way

Comment: The compiler is completely optimizing that first loop so that in the generated code there isn't a loop at all.

Comment: For future reference, I'd suggest stepping through your code using https://godbolt.org/. If you copy-paste your code with the compiler options, you'll see a difference in the generated assembly, which shows where the optimizations occur

Comment: Maybe `int main(const int argc, char*argv[])` helps. I.e. tell the compiler that `argc` is not going to change.

Comment: tried ```const int argc``` on godbolt, no difference with ```int argc```

Comment: `const` won't help, it's still not a variable that the compiler knows at compile time.

Comment: Here's how to optimise it: `n = argc * (argc+1) * 5000000;` No loops! No seriously. Why do you want to optimise this meaningless code? If you have real meaningful code that resembles this example, then please note that the first loop is nearly identical to the second one, but the results are rather different.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed-length loop was far quicker due to [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling):

> Loop unrolling, also known as loop unwinding, is a loop transformation
>   technique that attempts to optimize a program's execution speed at the
>   expense of its binary size, which is an approach known as space–time
>   tradeoff. The transformation can be undertaken manually by the
>   programmer or by an optimizing compiler.
>
> The goal of loop unwinding is to increase a program's speed by
>   reducing or eliminating instructions that control the loop, such as
>   pointer arithmetic and "end of loop" tests on each iteration; reducing
>   branch penalties; as well as hiding latencies, including the delay in
>   reading data from memory. To eliminate this computational overhead,
>   loops can be re-written as a repeated sequence of similar independent
>   statements.

Essentially, the inner loop of your C(++) code is transformed to the following before compilation:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    n += v[0];
    n += v[1];
    n += v[2];
    n += v[3];
}
```

As you can see, it is a little bit faster.

In your specific case, there is yet another source of the optimization: you sum 1000000 times the same values to `n`. gcc can detect it since around 3.*, and converts it to a multiplication. You can check that, doing the same loop `100000000000` times will be similarly ready in 0 ms. You can check on the ASM level (`g++ -S -o bench.s bench.c -O3`), you will see only a multiplication and not an addition in a loop. To avoid this, you should add something what can't be converted to a multiplication so easily.

None of them can be done in the second case. Thus, on the ASM level, you will have to deal with a lot of conditional expressions (conditional jumps). These are costly in a modern CPU, because their unexpected result causes the CPU pipeline to reset.

What can you help:

- If you know something from `innerLoopLength`, for example if it is always divisable by 4, *you can unroll the loop for yourself*
- Some gcc(g++) optimization flag, to help him to understand, here you need *fast* code. Compile with at least `-O3 -funroll-loops`.

Comment: I don't think branch prediction will be that important here - modern CPU branch predictors will have no trouble figuring out that every 4th loop condition returns false. However, the inner loop still takes about 3.5x to 4x as many instructions in the "naive" form compared to the unrolled one. There is still more to it (at least `clang` unrolls the inner loop) but that's too much for this comment.